# Error loading /ng2-bootstrap/alert.js as "ng2-bootstrap/alert" from /Scripts/app.modules.js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have not been able to find a solution by researching the error Error loading /ng2-bootstrap/alert.js as "ng2-bootstrap/alert" from /Scripts/app.modules.js.

I have tried these suggested solutions in **System.config.js** but they do not solve the problem:

```
map: {

 1. 'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap' or 
 2. 'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js'

}

packages: {

 1. 'ng2-bootstrap': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
 2. 'ng2-bootstrap': { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },

}

This is my **System.config.js** which I have read is likely the source of the issue.

   (function (global) {

    window.System.config({

        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': '/libs/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: '/Scripts',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler':
            'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 
            'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 
            'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
            'moment': 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
            'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or
     no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'ng2-bootstrap': { format: 'cjs', main: 
    'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
            'moment': { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
        }
    });
    var ngBootstrapPackageNames = [
        'accordion',
        'alert',
        'bundles',
        'buttons',
        'carousel',
        'collapse',
        'dropdown',
        'esm',
        'modal',
        'pagination',
        'popover',
        'progressbar',
        'rating',
        'tabset',
        'timepicker',
        'tooltip',
        'typeahead',
        'util'
    ];

    function ngBootstrapPackIndex(pkgName) {
        //packages['@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/' + pkgName] = { main:
   'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    ngBootstrapPackageNames.forEach(ngBootstrapPackIndex);

    })(this);

This is my **app.module.ts** which has been implied but does not seem to help.

    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { CollapsiblePanelComponent } from 
    './bootstrap-    components/collapsiblePanel.component';
    import { InputGroupAddOnComponent } from 
    './bootstrap-components/input-group-addon.component';
    import { CreateRegimenComponent } from 
    './create-regimen/create-regimen.component'
    import { AlertComponent } from 'ng2-bootstrap/alert';
    import { CollapseModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/collapse';
    import Approuting = require("./app.routing");

    //import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


    @NgModule({
    imports: [
        CollapseModule,
        AlertComponent,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        //    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserModule],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CollapsiblePanelComponent,
        InputGroupAddOnComponent,
        CreateRegimenComponent,
        CollapseModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent,
        CollapsiblePanelComponent,
        AlertComponent,
        CollapseModule
    ]
    })

    export class AppModule { }
```

This is my **Packages.json** where I have read that "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.20", is the correct syntax. This does not help either.

```
    {
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "name": "aspnet",
       "private": true,
       "scripts": {
       "postinstall": "typings install",
       "typings": "typings"
    },
     "dependencies": {
     "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.20",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "@types/reflect-metadata": "0.0.5",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.3.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
        "gulp-tsc": "^1.2.0",
        "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "typescript": "^2.0.3",
        "typings": "^1.4.0",
        "webpack": "^2.2.1"
      }
    }
```

[Here is my node_modules directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQC1g.jpg)

How do I get ng2_bootstrap to load without error 404

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to load ng2-bootstrap. For those out there trying to do this there are many many suggestions out there that simply don't work, at least as of February 27, 2017. So it is very frustrating for anybody trying.
This is what I somehow pieced together from the many ***suggestions*** I found. The most important suggestion being from ng2-bootstrap themselves. (Although ng2-bootstrap is not complete either).

**System.js**

```
(function (global) {
window.System.config({
paths: {
// paths serve as alias
'npm:': '/libs/',
'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap': "node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap"
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
// our app is within the app folder
app: '/Scripts',
// angular bundles
'@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
'@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
'@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
'@angular/platform-browser-dynamic':
'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
'@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
'@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
'@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
// other libraries
'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
// ng2-bootstrap
**'moment': 'node_modules/moment',
'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap'**
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
app: {
main: './main.js',
defaultExtension: 'js'
},
rxjs: {
defaultExtension: 'js'
},
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
main: './index.js',
defaultExtension: 'js'
},
'ng2-bootstrap': { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'moment': { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
}
});
})(this);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { appComponents as AppComponents, appRoutes as AppRoutes } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { **ButtonsModule, DatepickerModule, AlertModule** } from **'ng2-bootstrap';**

import Approuting = require("./app.routing");

@NgModule({
imports: [
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
// InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes),
AlertModule.forRoot(),
DatepickerModule.forRoot(),
ButtonsModule.forRoot(),
BrowserModule],
declarations: [
AppComponent,
IndexComponent,
IndexPatientsComponent
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [
AppComponent
]
})

export class AppModule { }
```